# Is this a function, variable or something else

Tags: java, enums

I was going through some application's source code and I came across this piece of code and I am not able to understand what this is.

```
public enum XStreamUserType {

MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM(MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER, "MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER",    new XStream());

private int userTypeId;

private String userType;

private XStream xStream;

private XStreamUserType(int userTypeId, String userType, XStream xStream) {
    this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.xStream = xStream;
    switch (this.userTypeId) {
    case MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER:
        loadConfigReader();
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```

What does this line mean?

```
MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM(MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER, "MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER",    new XStream());
```

Comment: Read the documentation on [Java enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JLS-8-9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9),

> The Identifier in a EnumConstant may be used in a name to refer to the enum constant.
>
> An enum constant may be followed by arguments, which are passed to the constructor of the enum type when the constant is created during class initialization as described later in this section. The constructor to be invoked is chosen using the normal overloading rules (§15.12.2). If the arguments are omitted, an empty argument list is assumed.

So therefore

```
MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM(MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER, "MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER",    new XStream());
```

represents an *Identifier*, and it is the first enum constant you declared (and it seems it is the only one), by calling the `private constructor` of your `enum` class `XStreamUserType` which has the following signature :

```
private XStreamUserType(int userTypeId, String userType, XStream xStream)
```

I suppose the `MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER` is evaluated to an `int`, `"MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER"` is a `String` and `new XStream()` is a `XStream` (you can see the matches with the constructor)

After this is properly defined, you can further use your newly created enum as : `XStreamUserType.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM`

Comment: hi loan, may i know what did you mean by " by calling the private constructor of the enum" and does these enum types have declarations?? where is it here??

Comment: As other objects, enum have constructors. As you can see, it is private (check your posted code) - it cannot be protected or public (if you make them so you'll have compile-time errors). Please check the link I've put in the first sentence, and go to the section 8.9.2. You will find all the details about enum body declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This is an enum constant being created with a constructor defined lower in the code.

Here is the constructor:

```
private XStreamUserType(int userTypeId, String userType, XStream xStream) {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an element of an enum, being initialized with it's constructor

c'tor:

```
private XStreamUserType(int userTypeId, String userType, XStream xStream)
```

Your enum has just one element, `MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM` but in a comma separated list you could add more.

For examples check this page: [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is an enum constant declaration. Notice the analogy with the last planet example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

In java enum can also have instance variables and constructors like a class.

Here `enum XStreamUserType` has three instance variables

```
private int userTypeId;

private String userType;

private XStream xStream;
```

while

```
private XStreamUserType(int userTypeId, String userType, XStream xStream) {
    this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.xStream = xStream;
    switch (this.userTypeId) {
    case MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER:
        loadConfigReader();
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```

is constructor.

`MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM` is enum variable(can be interpreted as object of a class), initialized as `MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM(MESConstants.MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER, "MES_CONFIG_XSTREAM_USER",    new XStream());` with values to its instance variables(as a constructor call).